# dart ffi - is it practical to replace all swift and java code with ffi calls

Tags: java, swift, dart, ffi

I'm developing a dart package (sounds) that makes a fairly small no. of calls into swift on ios and java on android.

Maintaining three languages is a real pain.

With the release of Dart's ffi layer I'm wondering if its practical to replace the swift and java components with pure dart code that makes ffi calls into ios and android.

I can't find much documentation around this which is a bit of a concern but was hoping that I was missing something.

Is this practical?